# how to set a dynamic URL to the XHR POST parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Note : Please note the question may be silly as I've just begun client-side development.
I need to make an XHR POST request to a dynamic link retrieved through JSONP. However for some reasons it doesn't work. Basically the POST url "youtube_url_upload" becomes undefined.

```
  xhr.open("POST", youtube_url_upload);
```

Here is the code snippet  :

```
    var get_youtube_service_url ="http://video.example.com/youtubeupload?jsoncallback=?";   
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  get_youtube_service_url,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache : false,
            success: function(data) {

                // get youtube
            //  var y_url = data.url;

            var token =  data.token;
            var  youtube_url_upload = data.url + "?nexturl="+encodeURIComponent("http://selling.example.com/youtube.html");
            calltoken(token);

            uploadFile(youtube_url_upload);


            }
          });

     var bytesUploaded = 0;
      var bytesTotal = 0;
......
```

```
 function uploadFile(youtube_url_upload) {

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(youtube_url_upload);        
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", youtube_url_upload);

        xhr.send(fd);

        intervalTimer = setInterval(updateTransferSpeed, 500);
      }
.....
```

Comment: are you sure you're getting the right data response? Try console.log(data) in the success callback and see what it shows.

Comment: as such the code looks ok to me. are you trying to upload video to youtube via ajax??

Answer (score 0):

the success callback get the a string as "data", not object 
it's may be a json so use

```
$.parseJSON ( data )
```